# React Redux is not working as expected with Next.js & NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, next.js

I'm working on an app using Next.js with redux by following [this example](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-redux) and here is some part of `store.js`

```
// REDUCERS
const authReducer = (state = null, action) => {
    switch (action.type){
        case actionTypes.FETCH_USER:
            return action.payload || false;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    user: authReducer,
    form: reduxForm,
});

// ACTIONS
export const fetchUser = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        axios.get('/api/current_user')
            .then(res => dispatch({
                type: actionTypes.FETCH_USER, 
                payload: res.data
            }));
    };
};

export const submitLogin = (values) => async dispacth => {
    const res = await axios.post('/api/login', values);

    // Router.push('/');
    // console.log(res)

    dispacth({ type: actionTypes.SUBMIT_LOGIN, payload: res.data });
};
```

and the client side such as `header`

```
function mapStateToProps (state) {
    const { user } = state
    return { user }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Header)
```

and when I `console.log('############=>', this.props.user);` the props & I'm not loggesd in then it's showing null but showing some extra data such as below screenshot

[image]

but when I logged in & `console.log('############=>', this.props.user);` it's showing proper data without extra data such as below image

[image]

what I'm doing wrong? please help me. Thanks

Comment: you have a spelling mistake here. ```dispacth({ type: actionTypes.SUBMIT_LOGIN, payload: res.data });```. `dispacth` should be `dispatch`.

Comment: This is not an issue, these mistakes in my post, not my code  @UsamaTahir

Comment: can you please provide minimal working code? I will debug the issue and let you know my findings.

Comment: @UsamaTahir It's very difficult to provide the full working codes because it's huge but the main functionality is in the post which is implemented for the redux purpose

Comment: It is very hard to tell what is wrong without looking at the code. one thing I noticed is that you didn't connect your action to the prop object here `export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Header)`.

Comment: When you are not logged in you are being redirected to some page, so axios gets HTML content as `data`, you are seeing that in your console. Check the network tab in browser dev-tools to check redirect responses.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is probably not on your React / Redux code but on your Next.js routes.

You’re trying to call an API with `axios.get('/api/current_user')` but Next.js is giving you an HTML response, that you indeed store in `authReducer` extracting it as `action.payload`.

You probably want to see [this section about Custom Server and Routing](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/#custom-server-and-routing).

Answer (score 0):

```js
dispacth({ type: actionTypes.SUBMIT_LOGIN, payload: res.data });
```

Should be:

```js
dispatch({ type: actionTypes.SUBMIT_LOGIN, payload: res.data });
```

Comment: This is not an issue, these mistakes in my post, not my code

Answer (score 0):

@MunimMunna is spot on. Your server is either redirecting you to an HTML login page, or returning an HTML error page for failed creds. In either case, Axios is seeing a 200 status code, so it thinks the response is valid. Your action creator blindly fires off the action with the HTML payload attached.

Consider making these changes:

- **Client**:

  - Add a `catch` block to your axios promise that logs failed response.
  - Pass an `Accept` header of `application/json` to tell the server you don't want HTML responses. If you are lucky, this might be enough to get NextJS to behave the way you want.
- **Server**: If needed, change the server to detect whether the request is an XHR request, or if `application/json` is the only response type the client wants. Don't redirect if those conditions are true. Return return a 401 status code instead. You can optionally return a JSON body with some extra error information.